# Insert data and select with jQuery - append

Tags: jquery, append

I have code jquery working fine with me ,

the problem is when I insert data and selected its append down then down then down :) I wont append  up of last append  data

here is code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#categorie-form').submit(function(){
            $.post("categorie.php?type=categorie",$('#categorie-form').serialize(),function(categorie){
                $("#showCategorie").append(categorie);
                $("[name=categories]").val("");
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="showCategorie" ></div>
```

i hope answer simple .

Comment: When you want "up", you probably mean `prepend` as in it inserts at the top.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: From `append()` DOC: `The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the first child, use .prepend()).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `$("#showCategorie").append(categorie);` with `$("#showCategorie").prepend(categorie);`

See [.append(), prepend(), .after() and .before()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846506/append-prepend-after-and-before) for a clear explanation of different functions to add things to the DOM.