# How append html in a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div in my html page with a id:

```
<div id="home">
```

I need to put some html like a link so I use jquery and my code is:

```
$('#home').add('<a href=..../a>);
```

The problem is that if I go control the DOM with google chrome I can see the element in the div but I can't see the link the page.Anyone can help me?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html or http://api.jquery.com/append. jQuery has just about the best documentation around. It's worth just skim reading it for an hour to see what methods are available so you can understand what it can and cannot do.

Comment: Two possible solutions available in your question itself. "How `append` `html` in a <div>"

Comment: just read the jquery docs or use some Google magic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.append(), prepend(), .after() and .before()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846506/append-prepend-after-and-before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use append() to append content to the div.

```
 $('#home').append('<a href=..../a>');
```