# Appending row to table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am fetching a table using jquery in the following way:

```
var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
```

I want to append a row to the table after the last row, I tried:

```
$("tr", table).after('<tr>...</tr>');
```

It appends after the first row and not last.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846506/append-prepend-after-and-before

Comment: you could do `$("tr", table).last().after('<tr>...</tr>');`

Comment: Must be something specific to datatables: normal `table` works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/ej7bsoz6/ (adds it after every row)

Comment: Can you create an [mcve]?  Maybe in jsfiddle?  I tried briefly, but I don't use datatables much and it gives 'cannot read mData of undefined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so it looks like your are using jquery datatables. so I would turn ordering off initially

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
aaSorting: []
});
```

then use the add row api for the datatable.  to add the row to the bottom.

run the fiddle below. scroll to bottom and click add row.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
aaSorting: []
});

$('#addRowBtn').click(function(event) {
  table.row.add(
   [
    "Ashton Andrew",
      "System Architect",
      "Tokyo",
      "45",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$56,000"
    ]
  ).draw();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
 
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="addRowBtn">
  add row
```

Comment: why have you disabled sorting initially? And it doesnt look like you have enabled it again, but it works :o

Comment: if you don't turn off sorting initially it will default to sort on the first column.  so inserting will follow the sorting rule.  but I wanted to keep it so that if a user clicked one of the columns it would still sort. so that is why I turned it off initially.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out. Could you help me out on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665354/sorting-newly-added-column-values-in-datatable-not-working

Comment: I get an error saying cannot reinitialize table. I need to pass no arguments to retreive the table.

Comment: bro living in 2034. thanks gpt gave wrong answer earlier

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) documentation,

> The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection.

Selecting the table and then calling `.append('<tr>...</tr>');` should do what you want in this case.

Comment: It's appending to after my first row which is a row with the titles. Is it possible to append after last row? the variable table points to first row

Comment: its actually inserting in my thead