# Sorting newly added column values in datatable not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable which has multiple columns and the sorting function works correctly for all columns except one.

For the column which doesn't work, I am adding the values to the table later on after doing a lazy fetch after a user action, whereas all other values in the columns are loaded when the table is rendered.

Is there a way for the table to get to know the latest values so that the new column can be sorted as well. To add text to the column I use the `.text` function of Jquery.

Comment: just wondering, if the sorting is on, and you are lazy loading the values for one of the columns, how do you know which row the column belongs to?  as in if they have sorted the table how do you know which row to put the lazy loaded data in?  is there some kind of primary key also coming with the lazy load data.  maybe you could show what the lazy load data looks like

Comment: There is an identifier for each row. The data which I fetch has the identifier mapped to a value. So I match the corresponding rows.

Comment: Yup something like a primary key

Comment: ok I'll try and work up a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

so I used the datatables rows every function to loop through all the rows in the table.  I get the Id which is column 0 and compare it to the id in the lazy loaded JSON data. if it matches I update cell[4] the age column.

run the fiddle below and click the load ages button. even if you sorted it, it should correctly get the ages in there, and they should be sortable.

```js
var Ages = [{
  'id': '1',
  'age': '63'
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'age': '66'
}, {
  'id': '3',
  'age': '22'
}, {
  'id': '4',
  'age': '33'
}];


var table = $('#example').DataTable({

});

$('#addagesBtn').click(function(event) {
  table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    var self = this;
    var d = this.data();
    var id = d[0]
    $.each(Ages, function(i, item) {
      if (item.id === id) {
        d[4] = item.age
        self.data(d);
        self.invalidate();
      }
    });
  });
  table.draw();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="addagesBtn">
  lazy load ages
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cell().invalidate() function
https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().invalidate()

or row().invalidate() function 
https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().invalidate()

Might be useful, if called in your callback from your Lazy Fetch.