# I want to add html tag without ending tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add html tag without ending tag like that `<div class="bottom-widget">` . For that I use jQuery prepend() method but full tag was added by this !

Html Markup -

```
<div class="widget">

        <h2>this is content 1</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code :

```
$(".widget").prepend('<div class="bottom-widget">');
```

Comment: you are missing `.` in selector `$("widget")`, should be `$(".widget")`

Comment: `$(".widget").prepend($("<div/>").addClass("bottom-widget"));`

Comment: you have an error use `"<div class='bottom-widget'></div>"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.append(), prepend(), .after() and .before()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846506/append-prepend-after-and-before)

Comment: _“I want to add html tag without ending tag”_ - that is not possible using .prepend, or any other such method - you can not append “partial” elements. What method could be appropriate, depends on what you are actually trying to _achieve_ here.

Comment: Yes . You able to realize my Question. “I want to add html tag without ending tag” .
Is it not possible ???? @CBroe

Comment: It is not possible, because it would not make sense. You are working with the DOM here, not _code_. And just repeating what you want is not an explanation as to _why_ you would want that. So, again: What do you want to _achieve_ here? Describe that, without using the words _“I want to add html tag without ending tag”_ or a variation thereof again.

Comment: Thanks everybody . This proble solved using "wrapInner" method :)


$(".widget").wrapInner("<div class='bottom-widget'>");

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) function.

And you code will be:

```
$(".wrapInner").wrapInner("<div class='bottom-widget'>");
```

Comment: `"<div class="bottom-widget">"` should be `'<div class="bottom-widget">'`

Comment: Thanks a lot @CodeLღver . this is solved by wrapInner() method :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need correct html so after this opening tag you will have another with closing one. For this reason you can use jQuery `wrapInner` function (http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) 
First extract(or create) the element you want to be wrapped in your **bottom-widget** element, than create **bottom-widget** element and insert above-mentioned element into it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".widget").prepend("<div class='bottom-widget'></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">
        <h2>this is content 1</h2>
</div>
```