# Update the id and not replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The two functions in the javascript  are both having a statement-

```
$('#'+key).html(data) 

funtion data(data) {
  $('#'+key).html(data)
}

funtion data2(data) {
  $('#'+key).html(data)
}
```

which is essentially replacing the value of the key. I don't want the replacement but basically add to the same data and then render the new value.

I am very new to Javascript- will be glad if someone can point in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `append` instead of `html`

Comment: note you're not using plain javascript, but the `$` hints to jQuery syntax.

Comment: Perhaps now would be a good time to read the [jquery manual](http://api.jquery.com/) if you don't know how to do a simple thing like append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want the replacement but basically add to the same data

Use `append` instead of `html`

```
$('#'+key).html(data) 

funtion data(data) {
  $('#'+key).append(data)
}

funtion data2(data) {
  $('#'+key).append(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without JQuery:

If you want to add just text, use `appendChild`:

```js
function addText(divID, text) {
    document.querySelector("#"+divID)
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

}
/** TEST **/
var number = 1;
var intervalID = setInterval(addMore, 500);
function addMore() {
    addText("appendHere", "Text #"+(++number)+" ")
    // do not add infinitelly
    if(intervalID>20)
        clearInterval(intervalID);
}
```

```html
<div id="appendHere"></div>
```

If you want to append HTML, just alter the code a bit:

```
function addHTML(divID, html) {
    var fragment = document.createElement("span");
    fragment.innerHTML = html;

    document.querySelector("#"+divID)
        .appendChild(fragment);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per first comment of @gurvinder372

```
funtion data(data) {
  $('#'+key).append(data)
}

funtion data2(data) {
  $('#'+key).append(data)
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846506/append-prepend-after-and-before) will help you to understand data handling on HTML elements using JQuery methods.