# How does d3 select array for iteration?

Tags: oop, d3.js, method-chaining

I'm going through this example of a force based layout.

http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/774d02a21dc1c714def8
The layout is defined as

```
force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(dataNodes)
    .links(dataLinks);
```

Later in the code though the author iterates through the link array with this call

```
force.linkStrength(function(link) {
    if (link.className === 'red')  return 0.1;
    return 1;
});
```

How does the author know that `function(link)` will iterate over the link array and not the node array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you write this:

```
force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(dataNodes)
    .links(dataLinks);
```

You're doing what is called a **[method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not)**. `d3.js` is known to use them a lot and each method chaining (with this framework at least) `returns` an object, depending of the `method` you call. With this particular code, it acts this way:

1. Set the size of the `force` object and `return` the `force` object
2. Set the `nodes` of the `force` object and `return` the `nodes` property of `force`
3. Set the `links` of the `nodes` object, and `return` the `links` property of `nodes`

So, each method chaining that you add returns something different. At the end of all the method calls, the whole thing will be considered as returning **the `return` value of your last call**, and it will assign it to the variable at the left of the `=` operator. Here, your `force` variable.

It's exactly as if you wrote:

```
force = d3.layout.force()
force = force.size([width, height])
force = force.nodes(dataNodes)
force = force.links(dataLinks)
```

When, later on, you `iterate` over your `force` variable, you necessarily iterate over the `links` array, because that's what you assigned to `force`.

*Tip 1: The tricky part is that here, and generally in `d3.js`, each method does not `return` the same objects. Both `d3.layout.force()` and `size()` return the actual `force` object, whereas `nodes()` returns the `nodes` object and `links()` returns the `links` object. It's cascading method chaining. Each element of the chain is called on the object returned by the previous method call.*

*Tip 2: you can understand from this that it's not necessarily the best fit to name this variable `force`.*

There's also a cool explanation that goes into further details **[from Scott Murray](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/chaining-methods)**.

Comment: Much appreciated! This explains everything