# Calling Level of method

Tags: java

In object oriented based programming language like `java` we can call a method of object by using objectName.methodName() -

```
aStudent.getName().equals(anotherStudent.getName());
```

Here to achieve the `equals()` method  I have to use two dots (.). In some case there might be more than 2 dots like -

```
objectName.methodName1().methodName2().methodName3().methodName4()
```

My question is - Is there any limitation of such level of method calling ?

Comment: Not a meaningful one, no.

Comment: as long as every method returns an object, which contains at least one method you can call.

Comment: Interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not

Comment: This technique is only reasonable if you love NullPointerExceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the method return an object, you can call any public method of this object, so no there is no limitation (none that you should matter.. there is always a limit).

Note that the approach may have no limit, but is not recommended at all, as it is harder to read, and harder to validate in one of the object is null.

Comment: you can chain in Java exactly the same way.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#Java

Comment: That's comparing apples and oranges, though.  You can still *chain* calls.  It's just different.

Comment: I did not say you can't chain, I said you can't chain like you could in other languages such as javascript.

Comment: that is true but it was not clear in you original answer

Answer (score 4):

There is no technical limit, since writing:

```
result = foo.bar().baz();
```

is equivalent to writing

```
bar = foo.bar();
result = bar.baz();
```

There is, however, often a design limit: if you are accessing the child of a child of a child of ... an object, you might be violating the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (and [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx/) article might clear things up further, in case you're interested.)