# how the flow of execution in callback function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got confused when ever there is a call back function.

for example-

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"><br>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name= "John";
});
</script>
```

I want to know in `<script>` tag **which function will execute first**,& also want to make sure is this function return any value to some other function which is used as parameter?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, I think you are asking about Method Chaining.
Read about it here

[Method chaining - why is it a good practice, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not)

In your case, the `module` function will be executed first. The object it returns has a function called `controller` which will be executed second.

The callback function will be called only when Angular sees `ng-controller="myctrl"` directive.

Comment: I am not talking about method chainning,my question is with call back function.I think ,in my question first  function function($scope) will set scope for variable name then It will return any value to controller('myCtrl', retu value of function($scope)).

I want to make sure how the flow is?

Comment: The controller function doesn't execute your callback and your function doesn't return any value to controller function. When Angular sees `ng-controller` directive, it invokes your callback with the scope as parameter.