# How to automatically update a *this return type for overridden methods?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, this, return-type

It's a nice habit to return *this from a class' methods, so that method calls can be chained. Consider this example:

```
template <typename T> class container 
{
public:
  container& append(const T& x) { 
    ...
    return *this; 
  }
};

container<int> a;
a.append(1).append(2).append(5);
```

However, when a new class is derived from this, it breaks the chain:

```
class int_container : public container<int> 
{
public:
  int_container& sort_ascending()  {
    ...
    return *this;
  }
};

int_container b;
b.append(10).sort_ascending();   // error: container::sort_ascending() does not exist
```

This can be solved by replicating the base class' methods and updating the return type ...

```
class int_container : public container<int> 
{
  int_container& append(int i)  { container<int>::append(i); return *this; }
  ...
};
```

... but well, my base class has 60 of such methods and I need several derived classes. So, is there any way to update the return type of those methods in derived classes, without having to override each single method in each derived class? And without using preprocessor macros?

Comment: Something similar to CRTP?

Comment: *It's a nice habit to return *this from a class' methods* - this is [questionable at the very least](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1103985/3959454).

Comment: Try to make these methods virtual.

Comment: Thanks Ami. It's a duplicate question, so this may be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) based solution for the snippet in question:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename R>
struct container_return_type
{
    typedef R& type;
};

template <typename T>
struct container_return_type<T, void>
{
    typedef T& type;
};

template <typename T, typename R = void> class container 
{
public:
     typename container_return_type<container<T>, R>::type append(const T& x) { 
        return static_cast<typename container_return_type<container<T>, R>::type>(*this); 
    }
};

class int_container : public container<int, int_container> 
{
public:
    int_container& sort_ascending()  {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int_container b;
    b.append(10).sort_ascending();
    container<double> c;
    c.append(1.0).append(2.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you will have to do the casting in each method you want to chain.

Comment: This won't work for the default case, e.g. defining a container<double> => the return value of append() is casted to double& instead of container<doble&>.

Comment: @following true, thanks for the note, I reworked the snippet, however it seems kind of ugly. I'm not that good with all the new c++11 templating stuff so maybe someone can make it look nicer however i think that now the logic should be fine.

Comment: YMMD, thanks! The syntax can be beautified by adding a typedef in the 'container' class: `typedef typename container_return_type<container<T>, R>::type thistype;`

Comment: @following true:) glad to help, it a shame that they closed the question.

Comment: I tried to implement this CRTP solution and run into trouble, mostly because an `int_container` now is incompatible with a `container<int>`, it won't downcast. I tried to solve that by adding a `template <typename U> container(const container<T,U>&)` constructor to `container<T,R>`, which actually is a complicated class hierarchy including type traits / SFINAE selectors. Worked fine with MSVC, but GCC melted down with a type matching bug. I decided that I pushed things too far and will go for the verbose overload solution now, maybe with some macros.