# Multiple dot operator (c++ class)

Tags: c++, method-chaining

I have to implement a class *Vector*, which sets coordinates of a multi-dimensional vector and will work when called with this specific code (I can't change this part):

```
  const int NumOfDimensions = 5;
  Vector x (NumOfDimensions);
  x.Set(0, 1.1).Set(1, 1.2).Set(2, 1.3).Set(3, 1.4).Set(4, 1.5); 
  x.print();
```

and the output has to be like this:

> (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5)

This is what I tried but couldn't get it to work:

```
class Vector {
float *coordinates;
int dimensions;

public:
Vector(int k)
{
coordinates = new float[k];
dimensions = k;
}
void Set(int k, float wsp)
{
    //Vector x(k+1);
    coordinates[k] = wsp;
    //return x;
}
void print()
{
    int i;
    cout<<"(";
    for(i=0; i<dimensions; i++)
    cout<<coordinates[i]<<", ";
    cout<<")"<<endl;
}
};
```

So I know function *Set* needs to be changed and probably return an object but I have tried lots of different ways and it just doesn't work. How should I modify it?

Comment: This is called "method chaining" There's some discussion here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to be able to chain methods of that sort you need to return a reference:

```
Vector& Set(int k, float wsp) {
  // ...

  return *this;
}
```

I'd argue that even though you see a lot of that in other languages like Python, Ruby and so on, that interface isn't very C++.

You'd be better off using `std::vector` to store your `coordinates`, the C-style arrays are nothing but trouble. This code actually has a severe memory leak since you don't de-allocate with `delete[]`, there's no destructor defined. Using a Standard Library container offloads that responsibility.

Another thing you can do to make this more natively C++ is to define a formatter for it so you can simply dump this to `cout` directly instead of having a clunky method called `print` which does it for you:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vector& vec);
```

That will permit the use of that formatter on any stream, not just `cout`.

Comment: Thank you! it works, cant believe Ive wasted 2 hours for this and then got answer here after 1 minute.

Comment: It's an unusual pattern to use in C++ which is probably why you don't see much call for it.

Comment: @tadman it's not super unusual though. I have seen it a number of times. googlemock is one example that I saw recently. But I guess it gets complicated if you intend to use it together with inheritance for example.

Comment: It looks similar to the Builder pattern.

Comment: @Zitrax There are certain schools of object-oriented design which love using it, especially in the Smalltalk-derived world. Some of those patterns have percolated into some C++ code bases. I'm not saying it's a good or bad thing, but just that in C++ it's relatively rare most likely due the complexity issues introduced by inheritance as you point out. Dynamic languages can get away with murder here, C++ will be a lot harder to keep tidy.

Comment: Isn't he ok with using an array? Aren't vectors still declared as a constant size in memory until the capacity needs to be exceeded?

Comment: @KennethMcKanders Each Standard Library container has different performance characteristics, so picking the correct one often means picking the right trade-offs. `std::vector` allows random access, can be resized arbitrarily, and is quick to iterate. The cost of resizing is non-zero but usually inconsequential unless you're dealing with very large lists or complex, expensive to copy objects.