# How do I run two or more methods in a class like a chain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to learn OOP but I'm getting very confused with how I'm supposed to run the methods or return values. In the following code I want to run `read_chapters()` first, then `sendData()` with some string content that comes from `read_chapters()`. Some of the solutions I found did not use `__init__` but I want to use it (just to see/learn how i can use them).

How do I run them? Without using `__init__`, why do you only return 'self'?

```
import datetime

class PrinceMail:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date2 = datetime.date(2020, 2, 6)
        self.date1 = datetime.date.today()
        self.days = (self.date1 - self.date2).days
        self.file = 'The_Name.txt'
        self.chapter = '' # Not sure if it would be better if i initialize chapter here-
                           # or if i can just use a normal variable later


    def read_chapters(self):
        with open(self.file, 'r') as book:
            content = book.readlines()
            indexes = [x for x in range(len(content)) if 'CHAPTER' in content[x]]
            indexes = indexes[self.days:]
            heading = content[indexes[0]]
            try:
                for i in (content[indexes[0]:indexes[1]]):
                    self.chapter += i # can i use normal                      var and return that instead?
                    print(self.chapter)
            except IndexError:
                for i in (content[indexes[0]:]):
                    self.chapter += i
                    print(self.chapter)
        return self????? # what am i supposed to return? i want to return chapter
                         # The print works here but returns nothing.

    # sendData has to run after readChapters automatically
    def sendData(self):
         pass
         #i want to get the chapter into this and do something with it


    def run(self):
        self.read_chapters().sendData()
        # I tried this method but it doesn't work for sendData
        # Is there anyother way to run the two methods?


obj = PrinceMail()
print(obj.run())
#This is kinda confusing as well
```

Answer (score 1):

Chaining methods is just a way to shorten this code:

```py
temp = self.read_chapters()
temp.sendData()
```

So, whatever is returned by `read_chapters` has to have the method `sendData`. You should put whatever you want to return in `read_chapters` in a field of the object itself (aka `self`) in order to use it after chaining.

Comment: Got it to work. I had to return self in read_chapters(). Or I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendData'. 
Any idea why this is??

Comment: In your code you were effectively returning `None`, which is of `NoneType` and does not have the method `sendData`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `__init__` has nothing to do with what you want to achieve here. You can consider it as a constructor for other languages, this is the first function that is called when you create an object of the class.

Now to answer your question, if I am correct you just want to use the output of `read_chapters` in `sendData`. One of the way you can do that is by making the `read_chapters` a private method (that is if you don't want it to use through the object) using `__` in the starting of the name like `__read_chapters` then make a call to the function inside the `sendData` function.

Another point to consider here is, when you are using `self` and don't intend to use the function through the object you don't need to `return` anything. `self` assigns the value to the attribute of the current instance. So, you can leave the function `read_chapters` at `self.chapter = i` and access the same in `sendData`.
Ex -

```
def sendData(self):
    print(self.chapter)
```

Comment: Yup. It worked without returning self.chapters or just chapters. But I had to return 'self' when I run it like frollo's answer. Any idea why that is?

Comment: My understanding is, that it is because there is an assignment. When you say `temp = self.read_chapters()` a return value is expected by temp, else it will be empty as there is nothing to be assigned to temp, hence `NoneTpye`. So, when you do `temp.sendData()` you are basically calling a method on basically nothing. Hope that helps. Also, please accept the answer or mark it as helpful, if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but, the reason to return **self** is because it is the instance of the class you're working with and that's what allows you to chain methods.

For what you're trying to do, **method chaining** doesn't seem to be the best approach. You want to **sendData()** for each iteration of the loop in **read_chapters()**? (you have self.chapter = i which is always overwritten)

Instead, you can store the chapters in a list and send it after all the processing.
Also, and I don't know if this is a good practice but, you can have a getter to return the data if you want to do something different with (return **self.chapter** instead of **self**)

I'd change your code for:

```
import datetime

class PrinceMail:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date2 = datetime.date(2020, 2, 6)
        self.date1 = datetime.date.today()
        self.days = (self.date1 - self.date2).days
        self.file = 'The_Name.txt'
        self.chapter = []


    def read_chapters(self):
        with open(self.file, 'r') as book:
            content = book.readlines()
            indexes = [x for x in range(len(content)) if 'CHAPTER' in content[x]]
            indexes = indexes[self.days:]
            heading = content[indexes[0]]
            try:
                for i in (content[indexes[0]:indexes[1]]):
                    self.chapter.append(i)
            except IndexError:
                #not shure what you want to do here
                for i in (content[indexes[0]:]):
                    self.chapter.append(i)

        return self

    # sendData has to run after readChapters automatically
    def sendData(self):
        pass
        #do what ever with self.chapter

    def get_raw_chapters(self):
        return self.chapter
```

Also, check PEP 8 Style Guide for naming conventions (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

More reading in

[Method chaining - why is it a good practice, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not)

[What __init__ and self do on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/what-init-and-self-do-on-python)

Comment: yes. You save the data in your chapter variable of the class. So, when you call sendData, self.chapter will have the data that was processed in read_chapters

Comment: Test it here: https://repl.it/repls/GrowingSizzlingCylinders . It generates 3 random numbers and concatenate them to a string then, sendDate prints it