# Reactor, best practice to retrieve nested (multiple levels) objects?

Tags: java, reactor

Suppose the following objects :

```
public class Employee {

    private Address address;
```

```
public class Address {

    private String street;
    private String country;
```

Which of the two following processes is the "best" (best practice and/or performance) ?

A :

```
return Mono.just(employee)
            .map(employee -> employee.getAddress().getCountry())
```

B :

```
return Mono.just(employee)
            .map(employee -> employee.getAddress())
            .map(address -> address.getCountry())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is more preferable:

```java
return Mono.just(employee)
            .map(employee -> employee.getAddress())
            .map(address -> address.getCountry())
```

because you can make it simpler by adding a separete functions for each getter, or using method reference:

```java
return Mono.just(employee).map(Emploee::getAddress).map(Address::getCountry)
```

It's obvious example, but in more complicated cases simplification of code by using method refecences could be significant.
Moreover, method chaining `employee.getAddress().getCountry()` isn't a good practice. You can read more about method chaining discussion [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not).