# Why don't Scanner methods return void?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've noticed that when using scanners, if I want to set attributes such as delimiter or locale, the methods to do so return the `Scanner` object itself:

```
public Scanner useDelimiter(String pattern) {
    modCount++;
    delimPattern = patternCache.forName(pattern);
    return this;
}
```

What I don't understand is that, if the attribute is changed (instead of it creating a new object), why does it return a `Scanner` object instead of `void`? It's not like I have to store the return value inside a variable - in fact, if I try to do so, like in the code below, Eclipse will give the message `Resource leak: 'lineScanner' is not closed at this location`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("accounts.csv"));
String line;
    
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    lineScanner = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Because that way you can call multiple functions in the same line. ``scanner.a().b()`` It's for convenience.

Comment: it's called method chaining. Related: [Method chaining - why is it a good practice, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not)

Comment: See [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). Some people don't like it nowadays, but it has its proponents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more for convenience than anything else. The return value can be ignored; it just allows you to chain methods for readability.

E.g.

```
lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").useLocale(Locale.US).useRadix(10);
```

This is more readable and shorter than

```
lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
lineScanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
lineScanner.useRadix(10);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I would argue the readability reason.  Imo, the second is more readable, the first is more of a shorthand for doing the same.