# Calling multiple function using object in one line

Tags: c++, class, oop, this-pointer

I was going through [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-pointer-in-c/) and found below code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
  
class Test
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
  Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};
```

This class seems okay for me. But the function call and its output seems bit confusing.

```
int main()
{
  Test obj1;
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
  obj1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Here, if I call setX() and setY() function in single line, then the output will be:
x = 10 y = 0

else, if I call those function as given below,

```
int main()
{
  Test obj1;
  obj1.setX(10);
  obj1.setY(20);
  obj1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

then the output seems
x = 10 y = 20.

What is the difference between these two function call. Can someone explain using this pointer?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: `Test setX(int a) ...` should be `Test & setX(int a)...` same for `setY`  else a new `Test` object is created (copy constructed) every time the function returns.

Comment: The term is method chaining

Comment: gfg is not a good learning resource

Comment: Bevare of code you "find", it could all too easily lead to [*cargo cult programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is not very good.

Comment: And that site has a bad reputation for teaching bad habits, bad code (like in your case) and often also *invalid* code.

Comment: @drescherjm "Method chaining" -- thanks for the vocabulary!  I see a discussion of it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not