Understanding "return *this" and class reference
I'm currently learning about object-oriented programming in C++, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the concepts of the this pointer, the return *this statement, and the use of references.
I've come across an example code snippet that demonstrates these concepts, but I'm still struggling to fully understand how they work together.
Here's the example code:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass& setNum(int num) {

        this->num = num;
        return *this;  
    }

    MyClass& displayNum() {
        cout << "Num: " << this->num << endl;
        return *this;  
    }
private:
    int num;
};

int main() {
    MyClass obj;
    obj.setNum(10).displayNum();  
    return 0;

}

What does it mean that the this pointer is returned in this example?

The practice is that is being used in your code is method chaining: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not

return *this; remember the this pointer is a pointer that points to the current object. *this dereferences it returning the object. The MyClass& instructs the compiler that you want a reference to the object and not a value (copy of the object). The reference is important because it allows you to modify the object by the chained functions.

For future reference: SO is a question and answer site. Note that question is singular, not plural. If you have more than one thing to ask, you need to create more than one question. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works.

You should take "What is the purpose of the this pointer in this context? How does it work?" and expand that into its own question, clearly stating which context you're referring to and what exactly you don't understand.

Honestly ChatGPT will be able to answer these questions very well and you won't have to put up with Stackoverflow nitpickers saying your very clear question "lacks focus" or isn't perfectly formed according to their made up rules.

Yeah. I have a great answer too... But if you're going to close your question before you get an answer why ask it at all?

@VoNWooDSoN It wasn't OP that closed the question

Well than whoever did close the question should have kept it open for the rest of us.

@VoNWooDSoN The moderator thought it needed more focus. I thought it was pretty focused around this :-)

Agreed, this is pretty clearly about this, which is something that a newbie could easily get tripped up on. But, again, the SO users are always so eager to tell people that their questions are crap.  Meanwhile this question would have had at least 3 answers and now it's unanswerable.  Terrible job Moderator.



What is the purpose of the this pointer in this context? How does it work?


In this->num = num;, this is used to tell the compiler that it's the num member variable that should be assigned to. With only num = num; you would assign the function parameter num to itself (a no-op). This is because the local num (declared as a function parameter) shadows the member variable num. It's usually best to not have shadowing. Had the function parameter and the member variable had different names, this-> could have been removed.
In displayNum, this-> could be removed. There is no shadowing so num refers to the member variable num. Returning *this "dereferences" this so that you can return a reference to the current MyClass instance. If the function had been declared to return MyClass instead of MyClass&, return *this; would have returned a copy of the MyClass instance.


Can someone explain the meaning of return *this; in the setNum and displayNum methods? Why do we return a reference to the current instance?


It allows for "chaining" operations. Example:
obj.setNum(10).displayNum();

Since setNum() returns a reference to obj, displayNum() will be called on obj too.


Why do we use references (MyClass&) as the return type for these methods? What are the advantages of returning a reference rather than a value or a pointer?


It depends what you want to do. In some "setter" methods, people prefer to return nothing - or return the previous value. In the application you got MyClass from, they seem to have wanted chaining.
Chaining is what makes things like this work:
if ( (a = func()) == b ) { ... }

In the above, operator= returns a reference to a. This can then be used to compare with b. Had the assignment operator been void one would need to split the above into ...
a = func();
if (a == b) { ... }


It could be noted that references are often only syntactic sugar (or always, depending where your sugar ends). For example, if the functions returned pointers instead, one could write obj.setNum(10)->displayNum();, no damage done.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica True. I wouldn't recommend returning a pointer unless I was planning on making it possible to return nullptr though. :)

I cannot tell you why. It's just the way it is written. What it allows you to do, however, is to chain operations on the same object.
If the methods setNum and displayNum were void methods, the code would have to look like this:
MyClass obj;
obj.setNum(10);
obj.displayNum();

Chaining can allow for nice and concise code, but as some answers in the link of the comment hint at, it can make debugging a bit tricky.
I don't think chaining in this particular instance improves the code, and I would probably not write it this way. But again, in the link of the comment are some nice examples where chaining looks like a good approach.
To answer your other questions:

The this pointer is just a pointer to the instance of the class.
Why not a value or pointer? A pointer just adds responsibility to the caller to make sure it's not a nullptr. There is no benefit to return a pointer since the object exists and we can pass a reference where the caller knows that the object exists.
If it were a value, you would create a copy and not operate it on the initial object. That's most likely not what you want.

